# Обновление RecyclerView в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-spinner

Имеется CardView который помещен в ResyclerView, который помещен во ViewPager. В ToolBar встроен Spinner. Когда кликнуть по элементу в Spinner'e, изменяются некоторые переменные, и в соответствии с этитими изменениями нужно обновить страницу во ViewPager. На сколько я понял страницы обновляются через 1 от текущей в две стороны(в подгрузке находятся 3 шт). Как принудительно обновить страницу, не прибегая к костылям как в коде, однако он выполняет то что нужно:

```
spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 1) {
                CalendarInfo.cngLast();
            } else {
                CalendarInfo.cngFirst();
            }
            int current = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current - 2, false);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current + 1, false);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current - 1, false);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current + 2, false);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current, false);
        }
```

Еще проблема со Spinner'ом, при запуске приложения выполняется код выше, хотя должен по сути при смене выделенного элемента.

[Скриншот эмулятора http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/13_8_2016/15/zB19ew2WvktFjVaEh5ZQ.jpg](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/13_8_2016/15/zB19ew2WvktFjVaEh5ZQ.jpg)

Comment: У ViewPager  есть методы для обновление, посмотрите эту ссылку http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287121/5634351